# spark reduceByKey performance/complexity when reducing lists with scala

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I need to perform a `reduceByKey` on lists. What would be the fastest solution ? I'm using the `:::` operator to merge 2 list in the reduce operation, but `:::` is O(n) so I am afraid the reduce operation will end up being *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Code example :

```
val rdd: RDD[int, List[int]] = getMyRDD()
rdd.reduceByKey(_ ::: _)
```

What would be the best/most efficient solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is:

```
rdd.groupByKey.mapValues(_.flatten.toList)
```

This will:

- Skip obsolete map-side reduce. It requires marginally larger shuffle but significantly reduces GC time.
- Use mutable buffer with amortized constant append time for intermediate aggregations.
- Flatten intermediate aggregate in *O(N)* time.

If you want map-side reduction you can use `aggregateByKey`:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

rdd.aggregateByKey(ArrayBuffer[Int]())(_ ++= _, _ ++= _).mapValues(_.toList)
```

but usually it will be significantly more expensive compared to the first solution.